# A way to activate a script on a tab in FireFox when a specific URL is opened

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, code-injection, firefox-addon-sdk

As the title says, I need my addon to execute a script that will inject some CSS  when a specific URL is opened. How would one go about calling on a script to run?

Comment: ContentScript firefox-addon-sdk: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are using the add-on SDK, this is done by using [page-mod (documentation on MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-mod).

The page I have [linked to on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-mod) has a considerable amount of information on the subject of using page-mod.  Quoting from that page:

**page-mod**:
Run scripts in the context of web pages whose URL matches a given pattern.

**Usage:**

To use page-mod, you specify:

- one or more scripts (or other things, e.g. CSS) to attach. The SDK calls these scripts "content scripts".
- a pattern that a page's URL must match, in order for the
  script(s) to be attached to that page.

For example, the following add-on displays an alert whenever the user visits any page hosted at "mozilla.org":

```
var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod");

pageMod.PageMod({
  include: "*.mozilla.org",
  contentScript: 'window.alert("Page matches ruleset");'
});
```

For your specific desire to inject CSS, you would use either of the following two [options to the page-mod constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-mod#PageMod%28options%29):

- [`contentStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-mod#PageMod%28options%29):     Lists stylesheets to attach, supplied as strings.
- [`contentStyleFile`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-mod#PageMod%28options%29):     Lists stylesheets to attach, supplied in separate files.

You wanted to know how to execute a script.  You wanted the script to inject CSS, but that is done directly with the options above rather than having a script do it. However, if you wanted to inject a script file to perform additional tasks, you would use the [`contentScriptFile`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-mod#PageMod%28options%29) option.